# Как проверить работоспособность ip адресов с файла на python?

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть файл с ip адресами как мне при считывании с файла добавить к адресам порт и проверить их на работоспособность после чего вывести в файл рабочие и не рабочие ip адреса с портами?

```
Пример файла с ip адресами:
178.215.189.67
178.93.9.173
95.133.134.103
178.93.47.155
178.92.177.234
```

Comment: Добавить порт в сам файл? Или при считывании из файла ip добавить в него порт и проверить? А чтобы проверить доступность, вам скорее всего нужно будет через `socket` попробовать открыть соединение и ловить ошибку -- если по указанному адресу никто не слушает

Comment: Вообще, делите задачу на более простые. Тут у вас две задачи: считывание из файла и проверка доступности. Покажи что у вас сейчас есть, чтобы было от чего оттолкнуться :)

Comment: @gil9red Порт добавить при считывании из файла.
В файле ip написаны так: 
11.111.111.111
333.333.22.331 
и т.д. ниже.
Сейчас у меня есть только этот файл

Comment: Добавьте пример данного файла в текст вопроса. Так же Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Comment: А что значит "проверить их на работоспособность", ведь там могут быть разные службы на этом адресе и все они по разным протоколам могут работать

Comment: @CrazyElf просто проверить работает этот ip или нет

Answer (score 0):

1. Уточни порты заранее известны или нет?
2. Порт один или разный ?
3. Здесь несколько задач

Как пример проверка доступности порта.

```
import socket
TCP_IP = "1.1.1.1"
    TCP_PORT = 80
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    except socket.error:
        print("Not available")
    else:
        print("Available")
    finally:
        s.close()
```

Comment: задавать уточняющие вопросы надо в комментариях. в ответе должен быть ответ. тем более если вопросу больше двух лет.

Comment: тем более если вопросу 2 года)